# Order States - Change 'Completed' to 'Shipment Pending'

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0

we have a store set up that uses the DHL Intraship module. (we've only just enabled it a couple of weeks ago).

The problem that we now have is that orders are automatically set to 'completed' because the shipment is autocreated

(Invoiced -> payment is received -> Shipping is autocreated via DHL Intraship -> Status changed to Completed because invoice, payment received and shipment are true).

But in reality we havn't shipped the items yet.

As you can imagine this is confusing as when many new orders come in, we aren't sure which have been shipped and which havn't.

Our aim is to change the default 'completed' message to 'pending shippment' until an order has been marked as shipped, after which it becomes completed.

How does one go about this?

We are on CE 1.8.1 and all modules are up to date.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the status label by navigating through `System` → `Order Statuses` and clicking on the Complete status in order to edit it.

In practice however, this approach will probably not be the most elegant because it may cause confusion down the line with Magento's native behavior. What I would rather recommend is as follows:

1. Set up your own custom model with a grid view. You'll use this model to track which of your orders have been shipped off
2. Create an event-observer to observe `sales_order_shipment_track_save_after` which is the event fired after creating tracking number on a shipment. You'll use this observer to then log an instance of your custom model saving the relevant data which will then be viewable in your grid.

That way you preserve Magento's core functionality in terms of the order status and labeling thereof, and you are able to keep track of active shipments.

Only when a tracking number is created & saved on the order itself will Magento then log a new instance for records purposes.